# Conditional statements on file names

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a directory of dat files named in the following manor:

```
4sl_shear11_scale0.dat,
-8_shear1_scale5.dat,
-18sl_shear0_scale2.dat,
...
```

I want to add a conditional statement based on the file name, specifically `shear_n`. The condition would go something like this?

```
if shear_n > 20:
    do the thing 
elif shear_n < 10:
    do the other thing
else:
    do nothing
```

Usually I would go of index of the file name but the index of shear number changes due to - and sl.
What would be the most robust approach to do this?

Comment: You mean `shearn_` rather than `shear_n`.

Comment: @jarmod before your comment I thought he wanted the number before the underscore. I'm a bit confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the format of the filenames and assuming you have access to them as strings, you can rely on some "algorithm" of string manipulation.

Something like:

```
filenames = [
    '4sl_shear11_scale0.dat',
    '-8_shear1_scale5.dat',
    '-18sl_shear0_scale2.dat'
    ]    

for f in filenames:
    shear = f.split('_')[1]    # split the filename and grab the second part
    shear_n = ''.join(d for d in shear if d.isdigit())    # strip the letters
    shear_n = int(shear_n)    #convert it to an int
```

Comment: Perfect, I had forgot about split.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your files have a number before an underscore, I think that will do it:

```
import re

filename = "-18sl_shear0_scale2.dat"
first_item = filename.split("_")[0]

shear_n = int(re.findall('\d+', first_item)[0])

print(shear_n)
# >>> 18
```